# Matrix equation with quadratic terms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, matrix-equations

Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ and a symmetric, positive definite matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$, I am currently having a hard time trying to solve the following equation:

$$ 
(A\,\text{diag}(x_1, x_1, x_3) - \mathbf{y}\,\mathbf{1}^\top)^\top(A\,\text{diag}(x_1, x_1, x_3) - \mathbf{y}\,\mathbf{1}^\top) = B
$$

Where $x_i>0\,\,\,\forall i \in\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are the unkowns (6 in total). On the other hand, $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector of ones so  that $\mathbf{y}\,\mathbf{1}^\top\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ and each of the columns of $\mathbf{y}\,\mathbf{1}^\top$ is the vector of unknowns $\mathbf{y}$.

Since $B$ is symmetric, there are 6 constraints on 6 the unkowns, which I believe to be linearly independent. However, I can't figure it out how to proceed to solve this system.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Vector realizations of a Gram matrix are unique up to orthogonal transformation. You might start by finding the Cholesky decomposition of B. Then find an orthogonal transformation of your matrix $AX-Y$ to compare with the Cholesky factor.

Comment: @Dunham Thanks for the hint. Following it, since $B$ can be obtained as $B = L^\top R R^\top L$, with $L^\top L$ its Cholesky decomposition and $R$ any orthogonal matrix, the issue regarding the orthogonal transformation wouldn't remain?

Comment: I am assuming $AX-Y$ is not necessarily triangular. I may be missing something, but I believe you need to account for the orthogonal transformation in some way.

Comment: @Dunham I see your point, thanks a lot.